# Разбивка по линиям в LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE

Tags: php, mysql, sql, база-данных

Есть CSV файл такого вида:

```
id;sku;desc
354;FEM65009D;<ul>
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
</ul>
```

Я помещаю этот файл в БД таким образом `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '{$import_file}' INTO TABLE {$table_name} FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' ESCAPED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES (".implode(",", $temp_lines).")` и получается так, что следуя условию в БД записывается все это следующим образом `id = 354; sku = FEM65009D; desc = <ul>`. После тэга `<ul>` идет перенос строки и это считается как новая линия (`LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'`).

Можно ли как-то сделать, чтоб `LINES TERMINATED` отсекал линии по определенному кол-во столбцов `FIELDS TERMINATED`? Например у меня есть 3 столбца(`id;sku;desc`), вот после записи этих 3ех столбцов должна быть новая линия.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос снят, нужно было добавить еще параметр `ENCLOSED BY` с таким же значение как и `ESCAPED BY`. Запрос целиком: `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '{$import_file}' INTO TABLE {$table_name} FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' ESCAPED BY '\"' ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES (".implode(",", $temp_lines).")`